# To remove character between numbers and join the numbers which is removed

Tags: javascript

I want to remove alphabet characters between the numbers and I used this code

```
    <html>
    <body>

    <script>
            str = "3a45 12c3"
            myString = str.replace(/\D/g,'');
            alert(myString);
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I got the result 3 45 12 3, but I need 345 123. How should I get this?

Comment: i didn't get.i want answer of that question

Comment: your actual code returns `345123` and not `3 45 12 3`.

Comment: and i need a space between 345 and 123

Comment: So what is it about `\D` (which matches anything that isn't a digit) removing spaces that isn't clear? Change the regex so that digits aren't the only thing you don't remove.

Comment: how can i do that?please give me answer

Comment: With respect, just a small amount of research would answer this question. Posting questions on SO is not a substitute for doing your research.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I prefered your first version ;)

Comment: @allnodcoms: :-) I decided it was...not rude...but unnecessarily blunt. The goal isn't to make people feel bad, but rather to encourage good habits. (But I hear you.)

Comment: How i sort this after getting this answer?

Comment: I don't think "alphabets" means what you think it means.

Comment: i means i want remove characters and i want to sort  without using an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just remove the letters `[a-z]` instead of the non numbers `\d`.

```js
var str = "3a45 12c3",
    myString = str.replace(/[a-z]/gi,'');

console.log(myString);
```

Comment: your answer is right but what this means console.log?

Comment: that means, you see the result in the console. you could invoke it with pressing key [f12].

Comment: and how i sort this numbers

Comment: with splitting it for an array and use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with a sort function.

Comment: without spliting there is any method

Comment: @bobmarti, no, you need [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) or an own function which iterates the string and sparates the characters into a new array (which is a good exercise).

Comment: @NinaScholz how i do that? I cant do it alone because i am new in js.please help me

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code you need:

```html
<script>
        var str = "3a45 12c3"
        var myString = str.replace(/[^0-9 ]/g,'');
        alert(myString);
</script>
```

In this example, the regex is only leaving digits between 0 and 9 and also spaces.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
str = "3a45 12c3"
myString = str.replace(/[^\d ]/g,'');
alert(myString);
```

Which means replace anything that is not a number and not a space with empty string (*see https://regex101.com/r/1rBRe4/1 for an analysis of the regex*)

Comment: thats for answer and how i sort this numbers

Comment: @bob you do not mention anything about sorting in your question.

Comment: yes but i now i need to sort  it how i can i do that.please help me?

Answer (score 0):

here :

```
 str = "3a45 12c3"
        strArray = str.split(" ");
        for (var i = 0; i< strArray.length;i++)
    {
        strArray[i] = strArray[i].replace(/\D/g,'');
    }
        myString = str.replace(/\D/g,'');
        alert(strArray.toString());
```